# Find SQL objects missing from source control

Tags: sql, version-control

We use Source Safe and are migrating to Source Gear. We know that we have sql objects (procs, triggers, views, functions) that are in sql but were never added to the source code repository. What is the best way to hunt those down so I can add them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an empty database and execute all SourceSafe scripts on it.

Then run [Sql Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Compare) to see what's missing.

Comment: I have the SQL toolbelt; just installed it the other day. Never thought to create an empty db and load what's in source to compare against my SQL object db

Answer (score 0):

There's an early access release of SQL Source Control, which links your database in SSMS to SourceGear Vault.  This could make source controlling your database easier going forward, http://www.red-gate.com/messageboard/viewtopic.php?t=12265.